# "0/the lazy/clever Peter": definite article with modified proper names

Tags: definite-articles, modifiers

In some grammar book I read:

The use of articles with names of persons modified by adjectives is varied. In most cases no article is used with names of persons modified by the adjectives **old, young, poor, dear, little, honest, lazy**.

> *... she is the widow of **poor Giovanni Bolla** ..* (Voynich)
>
> *He saw that **old Chapin** wanted to moralize a little*. (Dreiser)

When modified by other adjectives, names of persons
 take the definite article.

> *He thought Amelia worthy even of **the brilliant George Osborne**.*
>    (Thackeray)
>
> ***The astonished Tom*** could not say a word.

I wonder:

1. Is this a real rule?
2. Is this class of modifiers (old, young, poor, dear, little, honest, lazy) a closed set?
3. Is there any reason for this rule?
4. Is it possible to say, at least in some contexts, "the young/old/dear/poor/little/honest/lazy Peter"?

Comment: It's certainly not a "closed set". And I don't think there's really a "rule" that can be described in such terms. It's just that *on average*, the words listed (and doubtless many others) will occur more often in contexts where the attribute being identified is a ***permanent*** (but not ***well-known***) attribute of the person being referenced. Whether the article is present or not, there's only *one* person of that name contextually available, so *the bemused OP* here can't really be a device for identifying *which* OP I'm talking about, even though structurally that's what it looks like.

Comment: In reality, I think it's just a somewhat "poetic" construction that tends to occur more often in respect of "temporary" attributes. So *structurally* it seems more reasonable to include the article, when the particular *Tom* or *OP* being referenced is being disambiguated from *that same person* at other times when they *don't* have that attribute.

Comment: So @FumbleFingers, you mean that using zero article with "lazy Peter" means a permanent attribute? Then "the lazy Peter" should mean temporary attribute? 
Meanwhile I found "The industrious Peter had himself already spoken to Lisette"...

Comment: I would understand the set of "old-young, poor-dear-little" modifiers.
They are sort of emotional modifiers.
But "lazy" and "honest" stand alone.. And why not "industrious", "laborious", and "double tongued", "dishonest"?

Comment: To repeat, it's not a *rule* - there's just a *tendency* to include the article when there's a (perhaps hypothetical) possibility of there being *another* [proper noun] so we're specifically identifying *this* one. Where that "hypothetical" alternative might be either the same person at another time *(the bemused Tom)*, or another person of that name. In the latter case, including the article tends to "elevate" the status of the one you're *actually* referring to (and it really doesn't matter if you've never heard of any other George Osbornes who might not in fact be "brilliant").

Comment: I’ve been reading the story of “the industrious Peter and Lisette,” and the use of “the industrious” there is consistent with FF’s thesis: it appears to refer to Peter having been very industrious *that* day.

Comment: @Jacinto: Note that there's a significant difference between how *the brilliant George Osborne* and *The astonished Tom* work. The former is an example of a "well-known" (and thus inherently *constant*) attribute, in a usage that's at least *partly* intended to elevate the status of the subject (or underline the close association between the subject and the adjectival attribute). The latter is a completely different usage where ***the*** could in almost all contexts be replaced by ***a***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I got your idea about temporary vs.  permanent/constant/well-known opposition.

So I added the fourth sub-question:

4. Is it possible to say, at least in some contexts, "the young/old/dear/poor/little/honest/lazy Peter"?

Something like "It was the young Peter who stole the diamonds".
If it's not possible, then there's some idiosyncrasy with those seven adjectives..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a BBC World Service [*Learning English*](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv198.shtml) answer about *the* before nouns, Roger Woodham comments:

> It is normal to insert **the** before the adjective + noun in superlative sentences as there is only one of its kind in this category.

Generalising this idea, even if the adjective isn't a superlative, adding *the* before the adjective serves to give more prominence (power?) to the adjective, and hence the noun.

You use as an example:

> He thought Amelia worthy even of the brilliant George Osborne. (Thackeray)

Consider a modification to use the zero article instead:

> He thought Amelia worthy even of brilliant George Osborne.

The zero article version simply notes that George Osborne is brilliant. There's no sense that he outshines others who are also brilliant, or that brilliance is his defining quality (over perhaps tact or sportiness - I don't know the context), whereas the definite article elevates the adjective *brilliant* towards a superlative.

Regarding your numbered questions:

> 1 & 3. Is this a real rule? Is there any reason for this rule?

It's stated as a rule *of thumb* ("... *most* cases ..."). The reasons for rules of thumb tend to be empirical, rooted in the author's research and experience.

> 2. Is this class of modifiers (old, young, poor, dear, little, honest, lazy) a closed set?

No. Insert the zero articled "lovely" before Amelia, and the sentence is still grammatical.

> 4. Is it possible to say, at least in some contexts, "the young/old/dear/poor/little/honest/lazy Peter"?

Yes, use any of these modifiers in place of "brilliant" in your Thackeray example: the resulting sentence is still grammatical, and "the" still 'amplifies' the adjective. The definite article is also present in other contexts, e.g. ["The young, the old, and the economists"](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25486716).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a rule, more like a rule of thumb:

When an adjective describing a ***permanent*** condition is used, the definite article is in order:

> The brilliant George Osborne had a few drinks.

That said, with ***some*** adjectives (such as the ones in your list), no article is necessary:

> Young George Osborne had a few drinks.

Most important: when the condition is NOT permanent, an indefinite article is used:

> A very angry Tom was having a drink.

When the condition is no